# PHP Count Down Expiry Button or Link

Tags: php, time, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a button or link that will expire after 1 hour.

I'm setting the time the visitor hit the page with a cookie.

Most of the code examples I have seen only give the time that has passed and not the time left.

example: Link will expire in 0 hours, 30, mins and 34 seconds

This is just some rough code :

```
//Setting cookie example
setcookie('previous_time', time(), time()+3600*1);


$current_time = time();
$previous_time = $_COOKIE['previous_time'];

$time_diff = $current_time-$previous_time;
```

This is where I'm stuck, I have no idea how to convert the `$time_diff` timestamp
into a format like "expire in 0 hours, 30, mins and 34 seconds"

Many thanks.

Comment: Anybody can clear there cookies, so this is basically pointless.

Comment: then ill use sessions ... either way this is irrelevant its the expire part im stuck on :b

Answer (score 0):

To format your time difference, just do some math, since your `$time_diff` is just the number of seconds between the two times:

```
$hours    = floor( $time_diff / 3600);
$minutes  = floor( ($time_diff / 60) % 60); 
$seconds  = $time_diff % 60;

echo "$hours hours, $minutes minutes, $seconds seconds\n";
```

So, a value of `20712` [would produce](http://viper-7.com/77Dzxa) :

```
5 hours, 45 minutes, 12 seconds
```

Comment: this is not working for me.. only the minutes are moving and they are moving up not down... it has to be a count down

Answer (score 0):

Using your formula comparing timestamps, the difference is in seconds.

So, $time_diff / 60 gets you minutes; divide by another 60 to get hours; etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nickb that cookie based is tamper-able, but saying you mark the first visit somehow for an hour ahead when the link will expire:

```
// set when we are counting down to
setcookie('expires_at', time()+3600, time()+3600);

// we are counting down not up (for "expires in" not "valid since" logic)
$time_diff = $_COOKIE['expires_at'] - time();

$minutes = floor($time_diff / 60);
$seconds = floor($time_diff % 60);

// zero hours since the link will only be valid for one hour max
echo sprintf('expire in 0 hours, %d mins and %d seconds', $minutes, $seconds);
```

Then you can do:

```
if($time_diff > 0){
    echo '<a href="...">...</a>';
}
```

Comment: i get "expire in 0 hours, -22354237 mins and -9 seconds"

Comment: same here, the cookie array is set on next page load i think, so you might have to default time_diff to 1 for first time around